# Notation for whether tuple contains item

Tags: notation, vectors

Is there a function or notation for checking whether a tuple contains a specific item, e.g. if $(\{3, 4\}, 4, (5, 6))$ contains e.g. $\{3, 4\}$?

I know that for sets, the notation is $x \in S$ where S is a set - is it the same for tuples?

Comment: May I ask why you want this? What is a good notation can depend on the context. AFAIK there is no standard notation for this as it's nothing that is commonly done.

Comment: The " $x\in T$ " is fine. Your tuple is probably indexed so you could also say " $\exists i : a_i=x$ " where $T=(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ is your tuple. If you don't want to use $\in$ or $\exists$, you can say something like " $|\{i:a_i=x\}|\ge 1$ " after defining $a_i$ as $i$th component of the tuple, where $|.|$ is the size of the set.

Comment: @Vepir, Could you convert that to an answer?

Comment: @MarkS. Ok, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same notations as if you were working with a set, i.e. $(x\in T)$ is fine.

Alternatively, your tuple is probably indexed $T=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)$, so you can also say that "there exists index $i$ such that $i$th element $a_i$ is equal to $x$", which is written as $(\exists i : a_i = x)$.

If for some reason you want to avoid using the $\in$ and $\exists$ quantifiers, you can write $|\{i:a_i=x\}|\ge 1$, which means "the size of the set of all indices $i$ for which the $i$th element $a_i$ is equal to $x$ is at least $1$", i.e. that at least one component $a_i$ of tuple $T$ is equal to $x$ (i.e. $x$ exists in the tuple $T$).

The negation of the first one is $(x\not\in T)$, the negation of the second one would be $(\forall i,a_i\ne x)$, and the negation of the last one could be $|\{i:a_i=x\}|= 0$ or $|\{i:a_i\ne x\}|= |T| = k$.

There are probably some other less used notations that I'm not aware of, but in short, the best notation depends on the context.